# Angular 1.3 - Add Ids to option tags inside ng-options

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-options

I am using Angular `1.3.8`. I have a select list using an array as options with ngOptions and the syntax includes a basic `track by` expression.

I need to be able to add unique values to the ID attribute of the options (from that current `color`'s `description` to the current `<option>` element when `ng-options` is creating the option tags. Is there any way to do that? If not, can I use `ng-repeat`? I have tried `ng-repeat` with no success.

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.colors = [{
    "code": "GR",
    "description": "Green"
  }, {
    "code": "RE",
    "description": "Red"
  }, {
    "code": "CY",
    "description": "Cyan"
  }, {
    "code": "MG",
    "description": "Magenta"
  }, {
    "code": "BL",
    "description": "Blue"
  }];

  // Preselect CYAN as default value
  $scope.data = {
    colorType: $scope.colors[2]
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="plunker">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <strong>ng-options: </strong><select name="color" id="colors" ng-model="data.colorType" ng-options="color as color.description for color in colors track by color.code"></select>
<strong>ng-repeat: </strong><select name="color" id="colors" ng-model="data.colorType">
 <option ng-repeat="color in colors" value="{{color}}">{{color.description}}</option>
</select>
    <pre>{{ data | json }}</pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why would you ever need ID's on `<option>` in angular app?

Comment: @charlietfl QA testers demand it :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use [ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) with the syntax `(key, value) in expression`

> `(key, value) in expression` where `key` and `value` can be any user defined identifiers, and `expression` is the scope expression giving the collection to enumerate.

Using that syntax, the key (e.g. `index`) can be added:

```
<option ng-repeat="(index, color) in colors" value="{{color}}" id="option_{{index}}">{{color.description}}</option>
```

See it demonstrated below. Inspecting the options should reveal the **id** attributes set (e.g. *option_0*, *option_1*, etc).

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.colors = [{
    "code": "GR",
    "description": "Green"
  }, {
    "code": "RE",
    "description": "Red"
  }, {
    "code": "CY",
    "description": "Cyan"
  }, {
    "code": "MG",
    "description": "Magenta"
  }, {
    "code": "BL",
    "description": "Blue"
  }];

  // Preselect CYAN as default value
  $scope.data = {
    colorType: $scope.colors[2]
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="plunker">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">        
<strong>ng-repeat: </strong><select name="color" id="colors" ng-model="data.colorType">
 <option ng-repeat="(index, color) in colors" value="{{color}}" id="option_{{index}}">{{color.description}}</option>
</select>
    <pre>{{ data | json }}</pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh, neat, I see. But now, `"colorType": "{\"code\":\"CY\",\"description\":\"Cyan\"}"` is not setting the default to `cyan`.

Comment: Found out, I can use the `ng-selected` directive.